# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex') when trying to substring inside a loop (works outside of loop)

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error on line 167

```
string justQuantity = products[i, 2].Substring(10);
```

It works when I do it outside loop like:

```
Console.WriteLine(products[7, 2].Substring(10));
```

But when it's in loop inside case 4 I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex')
>
> at System.String.ThrowSubstringArgumentOutOfRange(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
> at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in E:\learning 2code\shop\Program.cs:line 167

I want it to substring quantity from string and covert it to int
I'm so confused...

```
int maxProducts = 10;
string[,] products = new string[maxProducts, 4];

string productName = "";
string productPrice = "";
string productQuantity = "";
string productId = "";

int countProducts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < maxProducts; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            // TV Screen
            productName = "Name: Samsung TV";
            productPrice = "Price: 4000PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 5";
            productId = "ID: s0";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        case 1:
            // Headphone
            productName = "Name: Hyperx Cloud Alpha";
            productPrice = "Price: 350PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 8";
            productId = "ID: h1";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        case 2:
            // Microphone
            productName = "Name: Novox NC-1";
            productPrice = "Price: 300PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 4";
            productId = "ID: n2";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        case 3:
            // Computer Mouse
            productName = "Name: Glorious Model O";
            productPrice = "Price: 290PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 3";
            productId = "ID: g3";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        case 4:
            // Keyboard
            productName = "Name: Redragon K530";
            productPrice = "Price: 240PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 8";
            productId = "ID: r4";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        case 5:
            // Gamepad
            productName = "Name: Dualshock 4";
            productPrice = "Price: 300PLN";
            productQuantity = "Quantity: 9";
            productId = "ID: d5";
            countProducts++;
            break;

        default:
            productName = "";
            productPrice = "";
            productQuantity = "";
            productId = "";
            break;
    }

    products[i, 0] = productName;
    products[i, 1] = productPrice;
    products[i, 2] = productQuantity;
    products[i, 3] = productId;
}

string dot = "\u2022";

string menuSelect = "";

do
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine(".-_-^-_-^.-_-^-_-.");
    Console.WriteLine(".Store Management.");
    Console.WriteLine(".-_-^-_-^.-_-^-_-.\n");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
    Console.WriteLine("< Menu >");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 1. Add new product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 2. Add quantity for already existent product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 3. Sell product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 4. List of products (with quantity).");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " ...Type 'exit' to leave program");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    string? userInput;
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userInput != null)
    {
        menuSelect = userInput.ToLower();
    }

    switch (menuSelect)
    {
        case "1":
            countProducts++;
            string newProductName = "";
            string newProductPrice = "";
            string newProductQuantity = "";
            string newProductId = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Adding new product...\n");
            if (maxProducts > countProducts)
            {
                bool validEntry = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Name of the product:");
                do
                {
                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userInput != null)
                    {
                        newProductName = userInput;
                        validEntry = true;
                    }
                } while (validEntry == false);
                Console.WriteLine("Price of the product:");
                do
                {
                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userInput != null)
                    {
                        newProductPrice = userInput;
                        validEntry = true;
                    }
                } while (validEntry == false);
                Console.WriteLine("Quantity of the product:");
                do
                {
                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userInput != null)
                    {
                        newProductQuantity = userInput;
                        validEntry = true;
                    }
                } while (validEntry == false);
                products[countProducts, 0] = "Name: " + newProductName;
                products[countProducts, 1] = "Price: " + newProductPrice;
                products[countProducts, 2] = "Quantity: " + newProductQuantity;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Limit of products reached.");
            }
            break;
        case "2":
            //to do
            break;
        case "3":
            //to do
            break;
        case "4":
            int totalQuantity = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("List of products:");
            for (int i = 0; i < countProducts; i++)
            {
                string justQuantity = products[i, 2].Substring(10);
                totalQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(justQuantity);
                Console.WriteLine(products[i, 0]);
                Console.WriteLine(products[i, 2]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total of items: " + totalQuantity);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
    }
} while (menuSelect != "exit");
```

I tried doing it outside loop and it works... I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When stepping through the code in a debugger, when the error occurs, what are the values used on that line of code?  What did you expect the result of that operation to be and why?

Comment: Substring(10) means "get me everything after the 10th character". So why do you believe there will be at least 10 chars in there? Your default case when initializing the data suggests otherwise.  Have you checked that its always the case? For example by debugging your code like David suggests?

Comment: @Ralf There should be 10 chars when i add a product in case 1, no? (I changed newX variables to ones i declared at start, idk why i initialized more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching on the index variable of a loop does not make sense. You can execute the different statements directly instead.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            ExecuteStatement0();
            break;
        case 1:
            ExecuteStatement1();
            break;
        case 2:
            ExecuteStatement2();
            break;
        case 3:
            ExecuteStatement3();
            break;
    }
}
```

Is the same as:

```cs
ExecuteStatement0();
ExecuteStatement1();
ExecuteStatement2();
ExecuteStatement3();
```

---

You data model is very difficult to work with for different reasons:

- An array has a fixed length. It is easier to user a `List<T>` which grows automatically as you add items to it. This removes the constraint `maxProducts`.
- Storing the properties of a product as different array elements also adds complexity and makes it impossible to choose an appropriate type for each property.
- Storing the label, e.g. `Name:`,  and the currency as part of a property value makes accessing the pure property difficult (as you have noticed with the exception you got).

Therefore, I suggest to create a Product class as follows:

```cs
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"""
         Product: {Id} {Name}
            Price: {Price}PLN
            Quantity: {Quantity}
            Amount: {Price * Quantity}PLN
         """;
}
```

Note that the `ToString()` override returns a string with the labels and the currency. If you have a `Product p`, you can now simply print it with `Console.WriteLine(p)`.

---

You can now simply create the list with:

```cs
List<Product> products = [
    new() { Name = "Samsung TV", Price = 4000m, Quantity = 5, Id = "s0" },
    new() { Name = "Hyperx Cloud Alpha", Price = 350m, Quantity = 8, Id = "h1" },
    new() { Name = "Novox NC-1", Price = 300m, Quantity = 4, Id = "n2" },
        // ... more products here
];
```

---

These changes also simplifies working with the products:

```cs
string dot = "\u2022";
string menuSelect;
do {
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine(".-_-^-_-^.-_-^-_-.");
    Console.WriteLine(".Store Management.");
    Console.WriteLine(".-_-^-_-^.-_-^-_-.\n");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
    Console.WriteLine("< Menu >");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 1. Add new product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 2. Add quantity for already existent product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 3. Sell product.");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " 4. List of products (with quantity).");
    Console.WriteLine(dot + " ...Type 'exit' to leave program");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

    decimal price;
    int quantity;
    string userInput;
    menuSelect = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower();
    switch (menuSelect) {
        case "1":
            var product = new Product();
            products.Add(product);
            Console.WriteLine("Adding new product...\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Name of the product:");
            do {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput));
            product.Name = userInput;

            Console.WriteLine("Price of the product:");
            do {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!Decimal.TryParse(userInput, out price));
            product.Price = price;

            Console.WriteLine("Quantity of the product:");
            do {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out quantity));
            product.Quantity = quantity;

            Console.WriteLine("Id of the product:");
            do {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput));
            product.Id = userInput;
            break;
        case "2":
            //to do
            break;
        case "3":
            //to do
            break;
        case "4":
            int totalQuantity = 0;
            decimal totalPrice = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("List of products:");
            foreach (var p in products) {
                Console.WriteLine(p);
                totalQuantity += p.Quantity;
                totalPrice += p.Quantity * p.Price;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Total number of items: {totalQuantity}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total price: {totalPrice}PLN");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
    }
} while (menuSelect != "exit");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created some products which do not contain any actual details. See the default option in your first `switch` statement. So when you choose menu option `4` and try to print the product details you encounter some products which contain all empty strings. Change the value of `maxProducts` to no more than **`6`** and it should work. Alternatively, and actually a better choice, is to validate the details before you try to extract the `Substring` from the object.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but if I set maxProducts to 6 then I won't be able to add a new product using menu option 1.

Comment: OK, then you need to add some code to option 4, to check whether the product entry you are dealing with actually contains real information, or empty strings. Just check if products[i, 0} is equal to Null or an empty string.